# Почему элементы списка не размещаются горизонтально?

Tags: html, css, список

```css
#MenuBar
{

    background-color:  #3399cc;
    height: 57px;
    width: 100%;
}
#MenuBar>ul
{
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;

}
```

```html
<div id="MenuBar">
    <ul>
        <li>о компании</li>
        <li>услуги</li>
        <li>технологии</li>
        <li>портфолио</li>
        <li>статьи</li>
        <li>контакты</li>
        <li>заявка&#8594;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#MenuBar
{

    background-color:  #3399cc;
    height: 57px;
    width: 100%;
}
#MenuBar>ul
{
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;

}
#MenuBar>ul>li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="MenuBar">
    <ul>
        <li>о компании</li>
        <li>услуги</li>
        <li>технологии</li>
        <li>портфолио</li>
        <li>статьи</li>
        <li>контакты</li>
        <li>заявка&#8594;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался забыл обратиться к элементам списка.

```css
#MenuBar
{

    background-color:  #3399cc;
    height: 57px;
    width: 100%;
}
#MenuBar>ul>li
{
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;

}
```